# HP Proliant DL360 G3: What version of XenServer is supported?

Tags: vmware-esxi, hp, hp-proliant, xenserver, citrix

I've spent some time looking, and haven't been able to find a decent HCL for the current *and* past versions of XenServer.

I have 3 HP Proliant DL360 G3's that I want to use for virtualization. They all have dual Xeon processors @ 3.06 Ghz, 2 GB of RAM (I'm getting much more for them though), integrated 5i controllers, etc.

I've tried to install few versions of ESXi and ESX, some with the DL360 G# on the HCL, and some without. I've had limited success with every version. I did get ESX 3.5 running, but I'm a little bit disappointed with it's feature set and want something a little more modern. I've heard that XenServer has a much broader range of supported hardware.

Does anyone know what versions of XenServer officially support the DL360 G3, or where I could find an HCL that includes all versions of XenServer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd really like to say that you should avoid using any G3 ProLiant in 2013... *especially* for virtualization... Anywho, the XenServer HCL does not include the G3 ProLiants. You need a 64-bit CPU per the [XenServer software requirements](http://support.citrix.com/servlet/KbServlet/download/28750-102-664874/XenServer-6.0.0-installation.pdf).

*One or more 64-bit x86 CPU(s), 1.5 GHz minimum, 2 GHz or faster multicore CPU recommended*

The [HP ProLiant DL360 G3 systems](http://h18000.www1.hp.com/products/quickspecs/11504_div/11504_div.HTML) were introduced in 2003 and went end-of-life around 2005. These are Pentium 4 Xeon processors. There are only two parallel SCSI drives. They're 32-bit only. At this juncture *ANY* modern computer will perform better (even a desktop).

Comment: If you try to boot XenServer on a 32bit platform it will crash. As I recall the G4s were the first to make it to the HCL, but @ewwhite is right. Even a low end desktop would do better and have more supported HW.

Comment: Thanks for your speedy reply. I know that these machines are old, but in the interest of time (I need a temporary hypervisor up soon), this is what I've got to work with.

But how can the system support 8GB of RAM if it is only 32-bit? Or is the system 64-bit and the processors 32-bit? Thanks again.

Comment: @ewwwhite Is there any way to tell that these CPUs aren't Cranford or Potomac Xeons?

Comment: The processors in that series of server were codenamed [Foster and Prestonia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xeon#Netburst-based_Xeon). The Cranford and Potomac were introduced with the HP ProLiant G4-series servers (*which I also don't recommend for virtualization use*). Those can run virtualization software in a limited capacity (but they lack VT extensions required by current virtualization suites).

Comment: @ewwhite Thanks. So, just to get this straight: Are these machines classified as 32-bit or 64-bit (even though these CPUs are clearly 31-bit)?